# OCRopus documentation?

Tags: lua, ocr, tesseract

Is there a documentation for ocropus?

I am looking for an explanation for the functions like:

```
make_SegmentPageByRAST():
segment()

RegionExtractor():
setPageLines()
extract()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A requirement of Lua API for [OCRopus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) has been filed in the [bug-tracker](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/issues/detail?id=68) list of the project.

They will soon be releasing this documentation in the next beta release(expected).

> First, note that you can use the command line tools without actual Lua programming.
>
> A good place to see how to use ocroscript is to look at the test cases in
> ocroscript/tests and the command line driver scripts in ocroscript/scripts.

**Note**: The Lua bindings follow the C++ API very closely (the binding is mostly
automatic), so C++ and Lua documentation are pretty much the same problem.